# Alien Invasion - what kind of parameters are needed when creating a module?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a newbie learning Python and I ran into the problem of parameters. The code is from the book *Python Crash Course* and I'm trying to practice the Alien Invasion code. My question is what kind of parameters are needed when a new module is created? Such as this one:

in the module "game_functions":

```
import sys

import pygame

def check_events():
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
   
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()

    
    pygame.display.flip()
```

when defining `def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)`, I don't know why the parameter "screen" is required when the parameter "ship" already includes "screen" as its parameter? "ship" already includes "screen" parameter in the main code:

main code:

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # initializing game and create a screen object
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    #create a ship
    ship = Ship(screen)

    #start the main loop of the game
    while True:
         gf.check_events()
         gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)

run_game()
```

my question is:
how to decide what parameters are to be put into the new module, when they are already defined in the main code?

Sorry for my poor English expression and thank you for anyone who could help!

more modules:

the ship module is:

```
import pygame

class Ship():

    def __init__(self,screen):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position"""
        self.screen = screen

        #Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        #Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

the setting module is:

```
class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        #Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

sorry for the confusion this is the first time I asked a question. My question is, when I want to create a function(here is in the first code I posted, called `def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)` (that will be imported into original code), a parameter for the function called "ship" is already defined in the original code, do I still need to put parameter that ship required, which is called "screen", in the new function and why? Thank you for helping!

Comment: what is a `ship` module? Can you attach it's source code so I can help you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry for the confusion this is the first time I ask a question. I simply ask, when I want to create a function, if a parameter called ship is already defined in the original code, do I still need to put parameter that ship needs, which is called "screen", in the new function and why?

Comment: I added the ship module, but the question is very simple though. Sorry for not being very clear, it is a simple parameter question.

Comment: If your question is taken in it's broadest context.  The answer is that you include parameters based on the purpose and context of the module being created.  You should only include parameters needed to perform the modules function and not include superfluous parameters.

Comment: yes that's why I have confusion here, "screen" seems to be unrelated to the `def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship)` here...

Comment: it looks like you have more than one problem pls clarify a specific problem

Comment: I have one problem but repeated three times in order to clarify

Comment: To answer your question directly, `screen` is available within the `ship` module, but not directly in the `game_functions` module. You could probably leave out the `screen` parameter, but then you'd need to access `screen` through the `ship` object, like this: `ship.screen.fill()`.

Comment: Also, I'm the author of PCC. This code is from the first edition of the book. In the second edition, the overall game is a class. It makes the project a little more complex at the beginning, but it means you don't have to pass arguments back and forth everywhere. To see the improvement, take a look at the final version of [update_screen()](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc/blob/master/chapter_14/alien_invasion.py#L49) from the first edition. Here's that [same call](https://github.com/ehmatthes/pcc_2e/blob/master/chapter_14/scoring/alien_invasion.py#L52) in the second edition.

Comment: thank you so much for replying, I will dig into your answers and check the final version. Thank you so much.

Comment: it did work! I tried to leave out `screen` and access `screen` through `ship`, as was put `ship.screen.fill( )` and it worked the same! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the `screen` being passed into `update_screen` is the same as the `ship.screen` then you could use `ship.screen` instead, avoiding the extra parameter. However, sometimes you might want to blit the ship onto a different surface than the main screen, so keeping them separate allows that to be done easier. If at any point you want to remove the ship, then you would still be forced to keep the `ship` parameter in the function because it contains the `screen` even though you wouldn't be drawing the ship. Additionally, keeping the `screen` parameter improves readibility.

Comment: thank you a lot! At first I tried to leave out `screen` but then the code had a traceback, and I tried to use `ship.screen` then it worked! So if I wanted to leave out `screen`, when I call `screen` I would need to add `ship.screen`. Thank you all so much for answering the quesiton.